# Will the original object be affected by this code?

Tags: java

A friend of mine wrote such code:

```
public AccountModel updateAccountPotential(Long accId) {

    AccountModel accModel = accountDAO.findById(accId);

    this.calculatePotential(accModel);
    return accountDAO.save(accModel);
}

private void calculatePotential(AccountModel accModel) {
    accModel.setPotential(some formula);
}
```

There's this method `calculatePotential` that returns nothing, but does some operations on parameter's field. Will that affect the original object in `updateAccountPotential` method?

Comment: **Yes**, because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value .

Comment: It would be nice to see the AccountModel::setPotencial method, but I guess is a "typical" setter so, yes, original object will be affected

Comment: `accModel.setPotential(some formula);` will definitely affect the `accModel`...

Comment: Yes this is perfectly valid code and will affect the object as long as `setPotential` actually does something to the object that is

Comment: If by "original object" you refer to the object for which the `updateAccountPotential` was called, `this.calculatePotential(accModel)` will probably **not** modify that object, since it is likely to modify just the `AccountModel ` instance.

Comment: You could just check it through `accModel.getPotential()` after line `this.calculatePotential(accModel);` rather than asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming `setPotential` is a typical setter, because the value passed into `updateAccountPotential` is a reference to the object. That method modifies the object's state (via `setPotential`) (presumably). It's exactly as though you did this:

```
AccountModel a = /*...get the account model...*/;
AccountModel b = a;
b.setPotential(/*...*/);
// Both `b` and `a` refer to the same object, and so the state of that object
// is visible whether you go through `b` or `a` to get to it
```